# How to correctly implement a javascript callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I am trying to implement a javascript callback in my function.  What is the proper way to accomplish this?
This function is called and will call the createImage function.

```
function getImage(reportId) {
    console.log("In getImage");
    var imageData = createImage(returnImage);
};
```

I then see my the message "In createImage done" logged. However I do not see an other console.log messages occur.  I don't see any of the messages in the callback method, nor do I see "All done done done" message.

```
function createImage(callback) {
    kendo.drawing.drawDOM($("#map"))
    .then(function (group) {
        return kendo.drawing.exportImage(group);
    })
    .done(function (data, callback) {
        console.log("In createImage done");
        $("#staticImage").attr("src", data);
        callback();
        console.log("All done done done");
    });
};
```

This is the callback function...

```
function returnImage(reportId, data)
{
    console.log("In returnImage");
    console.log("reportId = " + reportId);
    console.log("data = " + data);
    window.parent.buildSlideModel(reportId, data);
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the `reportId` and `data` values to the callback function, wherever you get them from.

Comment: Just remove `callback` from `.done(function (data, callback) {`

Comment: I see you are using promises. Using call back such way is not a promise way :). `createImage` should return promise itself. After that you can call `returnedPromise.then(callback(reportId, data))`

Comment: I originally had callback(13,data) (still didnt work), however I removed the parameters prior to sending this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things to note here, the primary problem is that you are redefining `callback` in your `done` handler, and it is `undefined`. When you try to call it you get an error, but that error is consumed by the promise. What you need to do is something like the following:

```
function getImage(reportId) {
    console.log("In getImage");
    var imageData = createImage(reportId, returnImage); // pass in reportId
}

function createImage(reportId, callback) { // accept reportId and callback
    kendo.drawing.drawDOM($("#map"))
    .then(function (group) {
        return kendo.drawing.exportImage(group);
    })
    .done(function (data) { // Don't redefine callback
        console.log("In createImage done");
        $("#staticImage").attr("src", data);
        callback(reportId, data); // pass reportId and data to callback
        console.log("All done done done");
    });
}

function returnImage(reportId, data) {
    console.log("In returnImage");
    console.log("reportId = " + reportId);
    console.log("data = " + data);
    window.parent.buildSlideModel(reportId, data);
}
```

Some things to point out here:

- You need to pass `reportId` through to `createImage` in order to be able to pass it to the `callback`.
- You should not redefine `callback` in the `done` function handler

I would recommend avoiding using callbacks altogether. Something like the following will work:

```
function getImage(reportId) {
    console.log("In getImage");
    return createImage()
        .then(function(data) { // use a chained-then
            console.log("Image created");
            $("#staticImage").attr("src", data);

            returnImage(reportId, data); // call to returnImage

            return data;
        });
}

function createImage() {
    return kendo.drawing.drawDOM($("#map")) // return the promise
        .then(function (group) {
            return kendo.drawing.exportImage(group);
        });
}

function returnImage(reportId, data) {
    console.log("In returnImage");
    console.log("reportId = " + reportId);
    console.log("data = " + data);
    return window.parent.buildSlideModel(reportId, data);
}
```

I'm not 100% sure on what your needs are, since you name a function `returnImage`, but it appears to be making a call to `window.parent.buildSlideModel` and not actually returning anything. If that is indeed true, the above code will still accomplish what you need. If you name a function `getImage` then you might want that function to actually return the image data (or a promise of the data). I have done that for you in the above code.

Comment: This does correct my issue.  However is this the best practice for handling a callback in a promise?

Comment: I edited my solution with one that does not use a callback, but instead uses promises. You can learn a little more about how they work here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/